# Oracle stored procedure cursor always returns zero rows

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this cursor in a procedure in a package:

```
PROCEDURE CANCEL_INACTIVE(IN_DAYS_OLD NUMBER)
IS
    CURSOR inactive IS
          SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE
          WHERE STATUS_CHANGED_DATE <= TRUNC(SYSDATE-IN_DAYS_OLD) 
          AND CANCEL_CD IS NULL;

  rec  inactive%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
     OPEN inactive;
     LOOP
          FETCH inactive INTO rec;
          EXIT WHEN inactive%NOTFOUND;

          -- do an update based on rec.id
     END LOOP;
END;

END CANCEL_INACTIVE;
```

Every time I test or run the procedure, **inactive** always has zero rows. However, when I put the EXACT same query into a SQL window, I get the rows I'm looking for.

What the heck?

Comment: How do you know the cursor has zero rows?

Comment: have you tested the query with exactly the same IN_DAYS_OLD?

Comment: I ran the function through the application that consumes it and I was not seeing the effects of the function. I then verified this by compiling in debug mode and using a test script to step through the code with the IDE I use.

Comment: @Florin also, I have tested with IN_DAYS_OLD being declared. I also tested it with just placing an explicit integer in its place. I've even replaced IN_DAYS_OLD in the procedure itself with an integer, and I still get zero rows.

Comment: can you test with a dbms_output.put_line('start') before entering and a dbms_output.put_line(rec.id) in the loop?

Comment: @Honus - OK, so you've changed `CANCEL_INACTIVE` from a function to a procedure.  Can you post the test script you used to show that cursor fetched 0 rows?  Are you certain that the rows you are seeing in the other session were committed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a good reason why you aren't simply creating an update statement in  your SP rather than updating a row at a time?  That would really perform much better than processing a row at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you'are testing on noncommited data.

Or: you're not commiting your update based on rec.id.

Or: your update does nothing. (the where clause is not satisfied by any rows on target table)